# Show out of stock simple products swatches in configurable (M2.2.4)

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, inventory

I want to show out of stock simple products swatches in **configurable product (M2.2.4)** to show size etc is available but `Out of Stock`.

I thought M2 did this with "Display Out of Stock Products" but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Seems there is a bug, when product has only one attribute Out of stock products are not shown even when "Display Out of Stock Products" is set. Report Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15047

Answer (score 1):

To be able to activate this configuration go to **Products -> Catalog**, there we choose any product and we go to the option of **Quantity**. Under it, there is the option **"advanced inventory"**, click on it and select the first box that says **Use configuration options** found under **Manage stock.**

This configuration will show all the swatches

Comment: This isn't correct. The question was to show the swatches when they're out of stock, not simply show them. This doesn't answer that question.